# Describing a Dual Cone

Tags: convex-optimization

1)Does dual cone define just for proper cone or all kinds of cone ?

2)Can someone show me a figure that shows a dual cone of a cone ?
In Convex Optimization by Boyd (P.51) said that " $y\in k^*$ iff $-y$ is the normal of hyperplane that supports $k$ at the origin"
what does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

1) It is defined for all kinds of cone, even for an arbitrary set (see this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_cone) for more information).

2) A figure is shown in p. 143 of Dattorro, Jon. **Convex optimization & Euclidean distance geometry**. Meboo Publishing USA, 2005. For the explanation, see also pp.141-142. Fortunately, all of these pages are available in [google books preview](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=VxuRF4NhjqkC&lpg=PA141).